# Как получить значение вложенного поля в группе полей в ACF wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Не пойму как получить значение вложенного поля в группе полей в ACF wordpress?
Группа у меня называется products, в ней есть два вложенных поля title и title2.

```
<?the_field('products');?> 
Выводит два поля сразу.

<?the_field('products_title');?> 
ничего не выводит.
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: [the_sub_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/)? Можно же просто заглянуть в [документацию](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/#loop-example), что гораздо быстрее, чем писать сюда.